# DatagridView bind from dictionary keys

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to fill the DatagridView rows with my dictionary values keys, but instead it's filling with the length (I believe it is the Key length).

My dictionary is filled like this:

- Key: Name of files
- Values: a class columns which represents the columns of this file

Code:

```
var dictFilesAndColumns = inputFiles.GetFilesWithColumns(txtSearchPath.Text);
DGFiles.DataSource = dictFilesAndColumns.Keys.ToList();
```

In this last line is where I'm getting the length of the key. How could I get the key value?

Comment: Did you try `dictFilesAndColumns.Values.ToList();` ?

Comment: It's spelled **length** - "th" at the end - not "lenght" ....

Comment: When you say key value. That's what each entry in your list would be. Or do you mean the value associated with a key? Which would be something like dictFilesAndColumns [whicheverkey].

Comment: @Anonymous it worked as you said, using .Values (I don't why as I would like to take the keys and not the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way to achieve it:

```
dictFilesAndColumns.Values.ToList();
```